# Angular Main.js file is to large after production build

Tags: angular, build, angularbuild

Iam using angular 16, this setup iam using

"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,

To minimize main.js size too as much small